# google cloud translate Java lib hang-up

Tags: api, gcloud, translate

1. I have config the gcloud follow this link https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/quickstart-windows
2. I have got the **Credentialed Accounts** [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BM8Qw.png)
3. When I call the translate API or Speech API it's hang-up long time with the error message

   Exception in thread "main" com.google.cloud.translate.TranslateException: Error getting access token for service account: 
   at com.google.cloud.translate.spi.v2.HttpTranslateRpc.translate(HttpTranslateRpc.java:61)
   at com.google.cloud.translate.spi.v2.HttpTranslateRpc.translate(HttpTranslateRpc.java:144)
   at com.google.cloud.translate.TranslateImpl$4.call(TranslateImpl.java:113)
   at com.google.cloud.translate.TranslateImpl$4.call(TranslateImpl.java:110)
   at com.google.api.gax.retrying.DirectRetryingExecutor.submit(DirectRetryingExecutor.java:89)
   at com.google.cloud.RetryHelper.run(RetryHelper.java:74)
   at com.google.cloud.RetryHelper.runWithRetries(RetryHelper.java:51)
   at com.google.cloud.translate.TranslateImpl.translate(TranslateImpl.java:110)
   at com.google.cloud.translate.TranslateImpl.translate(TranslateImpl.java:124)
   at org.org.fp.audio.recognition.core.TranslateTest.main(TranslateTest.java:16)
4. The code will like this:

   ```
   public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
   // Instantiates a client
   Translate translate = TranslateOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();
   // The text to translate
   String text = "Hello, world!";
   // Translates some text into Russian
   Translation translation =
       translate.translate(
           text,
           TranslateOption.sourceLanguage("en"),
           TranslateOption.targetLanguage("ru"));
   System.out.printf("Text: %s%n", text);
   System.out.printf("Translation: %s%n", translation.getTranslatedText());
   ```

   }

The issue is about account info or network ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very likely an authorization issue:

When using Google Cloud Client libraries, you need to download the Service Account's JSON file and set the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS to the path were your JSON file is stored. You may refer to [this link](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/reference/libraries#setting_up_authentication) for Translation API. The process is the same for Speech API.

Comment: Currently I only 'get java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out', how can I check my network, I can access google.com now.

Comment: This error doesn't seem to be related to the original one, you should probably post a new question including the whole stack trace. Anyway, the translation API endpoint is `https://translation.googleapis.com`, you may want to make sure you can reach that. If you are behind a proxy, you would need to add your proxy properties to your code.

Comment: Yes, I can access this link, but how can I user a socks5 proxy in java code?

Comment: It's worked after I am adding the proxy: Thank you ch_mike. `System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", "127.0.0.1");
 System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", "1080");`

Answer (score 0):

It's worked after I am adding the proxy:

`System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", "127.0.0.1");
 System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", "1080");`

Thank you ch_mike.